# Subtraction in sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Is this SQL statement legal?

```
     SELECT  firstName, lastName
     FROM  Presidents 
     WHERE  (endTerm-beginTerm)>4;
```

I need to find Presidents which had a term longer than 4 years.
can i use '-' in this query?
if not, what is the good way?

the data types are `endTerm` and `beginTerm`

Comment: What is the data type of the columns `beginTerm` and `endTerm`?

Comment: sorry. yes, iits beginTerm and endTerm ill edit it now

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8288636/27535

Comment: im not rob, but it seems that we got the same homework to do...
will add homework tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add 4 years onto beginTerm, then compare

```
SELECT  firstName, lastName
     FROM  Presidents 
     WHERE  endTerm > DATE_ADD(beginTerm, INTERVAL 4 YEAR)
```

This is generally (including using other RDBMS) safer than subtracting or calculating date differences because of how boundaries between periods are handled.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is correct. :-) However, if endTerm and beginTerm are DATETIME values, you may like to compare them with `INTERVAL 4 YEARS`

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, as long as endterm and beginterm column's type accepts substraction.