# Don't understand why this query doesn't work

Tags: sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Subtraction in sql statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288544/subtraction-in-sql-statement)

I have a table with Presidents names and I want to count how many (distinct presidents) served for over 4 years.

So I wrote the following query however it doesn't work. Error is:

> `Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax, near '*) FROM
>   (SELECT DISTINCT P1.firstName, P1.lastName FROM Presidents P1 ' at
>   line 1`

Query is:

```
SELECT COUNT (*)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT P1.firstName, P1.lastName
      FROM Presidents P1
      WHERE (P1.endTerm - P1.beginTerm) > 4) M;
```

Anyone see the syntax error?

thanks!

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288544/subtraction-in-sql-statement yet not the same user. Is this homework that you both have been given? If so, please use the homework tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the space between `COUNT` and `(*)`

or even better rewrite query to:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT P1.firstName, P1.lastName)
      FROM Presidents P1
      WHERE (P1.endTerm - P1.beginTerm) > 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the space after COUNT. MySQL doesn't like that

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT P1.firstName, P1.lastName
....
```

Also, why not just this? MySQL allow you to count distinct pairs directly

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT P1.firstName, P1.lastName)
      FROM Presidents P1
      WHERE (P1.endTerm - P1.beginTerm) > 4
```